# How do I create a standard iOS Share button?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios7, uikit, share

[The iOS Human Interface Guidelines say](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Printing.html):

> **Use the system-provided Share button.** Users are familiar with the meaning and behavior of this button, so it’s a good idea to use it when possible. The main exception to this is if your app does not contain a toolbar or navigation bar[, as] the Share button can only be used in a toolbar or navigation bar.

OK, but how do I “use the system-provided Share button”? [A search of the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/search/?q=share+button) turns up nothing useful.

I've gathered that [I should use UIActivityViewController in my *response* to the button being tapped](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15641384/30461), but how would I create the standard Share button in the first place?

Comment: thank you for quoting the HIG, b/c that link is redirected, and that copy is lost :(

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The standard Share button is a UIBarButtonItem (so it can only go on a navigation bar or toolbar). You need to [create a “system item”](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIBarButtonItem/initWithBarButtonSystemItem:target:action:); specifically, [an “action item”](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/UIBarButtonSystemItemAction). The “action” bar button item is the Share button.

Answer (score 27):

Here is the code. I am assuming you are inside ViewController so self has navigationItem property.

```
UIBarButtonItem *shareButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction
                     target:self
                     action:@selector(shareAction:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = shareButton;
```

Answer (score 13):

This goes in your viewDidLoad:

```
UIBarButtonItem *shareButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction
                                target:self
                                action:@selector(compartir:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = shareButton;
```

And define your selector method to be called as action (in my case named as "compartir"):

```
- (void) compartir:(id)sender{

//Si no


NSLog(@"shareButton pressed");


NSString *stringtoshare= @"This is a string to share";
UIImage *imagetoshare = img; //This is an image to share.

NSArray *activityItems = @[stringtoshare, imagetoshare];
UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypePostToTwitter, UIActivityTypePostToWeibo];
[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Main.storyboard -> Bar Button Item -> Inspector -> System Item 
chose "Action"[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here is the code for Swift 3.

```
func addShareBarButtonItem() {

    let shareButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Action, target: self, action: #selector(MyViewController.shareButtonPressed))

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = shareButton
}

func shareButtonPressed() {
    //Do something now!
}
```

Answer (score 3):

only my two cents for swift 4 / Xcode 10:

1) action has initial char changed:

```
let shareButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .action, target: self, action: #selector(shareButtonPressed))
```

2) add @obj:

```
@objc func shareButtonPressed() {
    //Do something now!
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The system-provided Action button can also be fully created with an Interface Builder. To do so just drag & drop the **UIToolbar** to your view. Than drag & drop the **UIBarButtonItem** into the UIToolbar. As next step select in the view hierarchy the **UIBarButtonItem**, go to the Attribute Inspector and select as System Item the "Action". **Done!**

Additionally it is possible to connect the **UIBarButtonItem** with your class as IBOutlet or IBAction.

Please note: I use as a reference an Xcode 7.