# How to create a UIButton using the system's Share image?

Tags: ios, uibutton, sharing

I know how to [create a standard Share button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19736440/how-do-i-create-a-standard-ios-share-button) if that button lives in a navigation bar or toolbar.

But what if I need to create a UIButton and want to use iOS's standard "Share" image? Can I access the system's image or do I have create my own image?

[image]

Comment: You have to create your own image and add it as background image your UIButton programmatically or through Attributes Inspector